# How can I use this toFixed(2) in these codes?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

It already shows the correct percentage. However, this is what it looks like:

```
8.333333333333332
```

How can I make it display like this: `8.33%`

Putting it inside this will cause an error:

```
acc[key] = (acc[key] || 0) + (1 / totalUsers) * 100.toFixed(2);
```

Below are the codes:

```
const movies = data.filter(v => v.genre?.selected == "Movie");
const counts = movies.reduce((acc, cur) => {
    return !cur["1"]?.drama
    ? acc:
    Object.entries(cur["1"].drama).reduce((acc, [key,value]) => { 
        if (value) { 
            acc[key] = (acc[key] || 0) + (1 / totalUsers) * 100;
        }
        return acc;
    }, acc)
}, {})
```

This is a part of the data:

```
 const totalUsers = 12

const data = [{
  "1": { drama: { Comedy: true, Romance: true, BuddyComedy: false } },
  "2": {
    drama2: { Tragedy: true},
    others: "Dystopian",
  },
  id: "zaMR9TR7hNV3p3VFNumyNbXMto93",
  genre: {
    selected: "Movie",
  },
  displayName: "p1"
}, 
 {
  "1": { drama: { Tragedy: true, Comedy : true} },
  "2": {
    drama2: { Romance: true}
  },
  id: "zaMR9TR7hNV3p3VFNumyNbXMto93", //sample id
  genre: {
    selected: "Movie",
  },
  displayName: "p2"
}]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to wrap the `100` in brackets.

If you don't, the interpreter believes the number is a decimal, and tries to parse the segment after the period ("`toFixed(2)`") as a number, causing an error.

---

In your case...

You'll have to parse the number using the [`Number` constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/Number), *then* call `toFixed()`:

```js
Number(+(acc[key] || 0) + (1 / totalUsers) * (100)).toFixed(2);
```

<sup>Take note of the [unary plus operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Unary_plus) before "`(acc[key] || 0)`" used to parse it into a number, to ensure that we aren't concatenating strings. (if you don't add it, you'll end up with `NaN`)</sup>

Working code:

```js
const totalUsers = 12

const data=[{1:{drama:{Comedy:!0,Romance:!0,BuddyComedy:!1}},2:{drama2:{Tragedy:!0},others:"Dystopian"},id:"zaMR9TR7hNV3p3VFNumyNbXMto93",genre:{selected:"Movie"},displayName:"p1"},{1:{drama:{Tragedy:!0,Comedy:!0}},2:{drama2:{Romance:!0}},id:"zaMR9TR7hNV3p3VFNumyNbXMto93",genre:{selected:"Movie"},displayName:"p2"}];

const movies = data.filter(v => v.genre?.selected == "Movie");
const counts = movies.reduce((acc, cur) => {
    return !cur["1"]?.drama ?
        acc :
        Object.entries(cur["1"].drama).reduce((acc, [key, value]) => {
            if (value) {
                acc[key] = Number(+(acc[key] || 0) + (1 / totalUsers) * (100)).toFixed(2);
            }
            return acc;
        }, acc)
}, {})


console.log(JSON.stringify(counts,0, 2))
```

Comment: It still shows this `8.333333333333332`

Comment: @Jenn Can you provide sample data for `movies`?

Comment: I've added it in the post. Thank you

Comment: @Spetric Hello, I've added the `totalUsers=12`. So for like `Comedy`, it'll be `(1\12)*100` which would produce the output of `8.33333333333333`

Comment: @Spetric Sorry, it was supposed to be `return !cur["1"]?.drama`, I got confused with the other project

Answer (score 1):

You loose precision if you repeatedly round the number and parse it throughout the calculation. To preserve the precision of your numbers as much as possible, rounding should only be done once after all calculation completed.

```js
const totalUsers = 12

const data=[{1:{drama:{Comedy:!0,Romance:!0,BuddyComedy:!1}},2:{drama2:{Tragedy:!0},others:"Dystopian"},id:"zaMR9TR7hNV3p3VFNumyNbXMto93",genre:{selected:"Movie"},displayName:"p1"},{1:{drama:{Tragedy:!0,Comedy:!0}},2:{drama2:{Romance:!0}},id:"zaMR9TR7hNV3p3VFNumyNbXMto93",genre:{selected:"Movie"},displayName:"p2"}];

const movies = data.filter(v => v.genre?.selected == "Movie");
const counts = movies.reduce((acc, cur) => {
    return !cur["1"]?.drama ?
        acc :
        Object.entries(cur["1"].drama).reduce((acc, [key, value]) => {
            if (value) {
                acc[key] = (acc[key] || 0) + (1 / totalUsers) * 100;
            }
            return acc;
        }, acc)
}, {})

const rounded = Object.entries(counts).reduce((acc,[key,value])=>{
  return {...acc,[key]:value.toFixed(2)};
},{});

console.log(rounded);
```

Answer (score 0):

`acc[key] = ((acc[key] || 0) + (1 / totalUsers) * 100).toFixed(2);`

Wrap the whole thing in brackets and then put .toFixed(2)

```
const movies = data.filter(v => v.genre?.selected == "Movie");
const counts = movies.reduce((acc, cur) => {
    return !cur["1"]?.sideEffects1
    ? acc:
    Object.entries(cur["1"].drama).reduce((acc, [key,value]) => { 
        if (value) { 
            acc[key] = ((acc[key] || 0) + (1 / totalUsers) * 100).toFixed(2);
        }
        return acc;
    }, acc)
}, {})
```

Comment: It shows this error `((acc[key] || 0) + ((1 / totalUsers) * 100)).toFixed is not a function`

Comment: This throws an error: `"Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '.'"`